# Extract string from path/dir using Make

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I’ve a **Makefile** with multiple git repo’s which I need to clone 
I use the following which works

```
clone:
    git clone https://github.company.corp/dev-wi/ws-led.git
    git clone https://github.company.corp/dev-wi/tools-extension.git
    git clone https://github.company.corp/dev-wi/javt-ra.git
```

While the following code works, I want to do something like this in loop for all the repos on the list

```
build:
    cd ws-led;  \
    docker build -t ws-led .
    cd tools-extension;  \
    docker build -t tools-extension .
    ...
```

For each repo I need to change dir
And run the docker build , 
I want to avoid doing this over and over again ...
I know that I need to extract the string after **/dev-wi/** as this is the repo directory which I need to run docker build on. 
since I’ve many repo how can I do it easily ?

I try with subset however I have also the git command (in clone) so it doesn't work,any idea?

**update**
I've created the A new makefile and use only this code (the `ws-led` and `tools-extension` is folders in the same level of of the makefile

```
repos := ws-led tools-extension

.PHONY: all

all: $(patsubst%,%/docker-build.log,$(repos))

%/docker-build.log: %/.git
    cd $*; docker build -t $* . >&2 | tee docker-build.log
```

**I got error:**

`make: Nothing to be done for`all'.`

what am I missing here ?

**I try to simplify it but removing the git and let say that the folders (repo) existing on the same level of the makefile**

**UPDATE**

Im change the makefile to be under the root

```
proj
  - ws-led
  — Dockerfile
 -tools-ext
 —Dockerfile    
-Makefile
```

I try with the following

```
all: pre docker-build
.PHONY: pre docker-build
repos := ws-led tools-ext

pre:
    $(patsubst %,%docker-build,$(repos))

docker-build:pre
    cd $*; docker build -t $* . >&2 | tee docker-build
```

**when I run make I got the following error**

```
ws-leddocker-build  ws-leddocker-build
make: ws-leddocker-build: No such file or directory
```

Any idea?

Comment: Add the variable e.g., `MY_REPOS=ws-led tools-extension javt-ra` and use `$(foreach)` over it. Also, you may automatically render the individual build rules (e.g., `build-ws-led` & etc) and make the `build` target depend on it (also w/ `$(foreach)`

Comment: @zaufi - can you please add it as answer ?

Comment: The `pre` target doesn't make any sense, the `$(patsubst ...)` is a prerequisite and should be on the same line as the colon. The indented body of a recipe should be a sequence of shell commands. If you want `pre`. But your refactoring with this recipe has a number of additional problems; perhaps if you have new oi different requirements, a new separate question *just* about those would make sense.

Comment: @tripleee This is what I try to do and you close it :) ,anyway im closing this question and open new one which more simple

Comment: Yeah, in retrospect that was perhaps less than ideal. I'll update my answer to hopefully clarify what it's doing.

Comment: @tripleee - thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping is generally something you want to avoid. Instead, declare a series of targets for each repo.

```
repos := ws-led tools-extension javt-ra

.PHONY: all clone
all: $(patsubst %,%/.built,$(repos))
clone: $(patsubst %,%/.git,$(repos))

%/.built: %/.git
    cd $*; docker build -t $* .
    touch $@

%/.git:
    git clone https://github.company.corp/dev-wi/$*.git
```

The `.built` flag file is a bit of a wart, and could usefully be replaced with something more useful, like the output from `docker build`.

```
all: $(patsubst %,%/docker-build.log,$(repos))

%/docker-build.log: %/.git
    cd $*; docker build -t $* . >&2 | tee docker-build.log
```

The reason we generally try to avoid loops is to allow `make` to do its primary job properly -- avoid rerunning commands when a target is already up to date.  So, for example, if you only changed `ws-led`, you don't want to force the other two to be rebuilt as well.

Having said that, the `$(patsubst ...)` is a loop of sorts; it basically loops over `repos` and creates a small piece of text around each.  Without the `patsubst` we could write

```
all: ws-led/.built tools-extension/.built javt-ra/.built
```

which simply says that to make `all` we need to make those three; and then

```
%/.built: %/.git
```

says that for anything matching the pattern, it depends on the same stem with `/.git` after it. So in an otherwise empty directory, `make` would find that

- to make `all`, we need to make `ws-led/.built`, `tools-extension/.built`, and `javt-ra/.built`;

  - to make `ws-led/.built`, we need to make `ws-led/.git`;

    - to make `ws-led/.git`, we need to

    ```sh
    git clone https://github.company.corp/dev-wi/ws-led.git
    ```

    - then once this prerequisite is satisfied,

    ```sh
    cd ws-led; docker build -t ws-led .
    touch ws-led/.built
    ```
  - to make `tools-extension/.built`, we need to make `tools-extension/.git`;

    - to make `tools-extension/.git`, we need to

    ```sh
    git clone https://github.company.corp/dev-wi/tools-extension.git
    ```

    ... etc etc.

In the future, when `make` finds that `ws-led` is newer than `ws-led/.built` it will build it again; but if it is not, it will conclude that no work needs to be done, etc for the other targets. This is how we avoid building things needlessly; but it obviously requires that the `Makefile` properly contains a formalization of every relevant dependency. (In this case, you would ideally like for there to be a way to know when the Git upstream has changed and something needs to be pulled by the local `Makefile`; this currently simply regards everything as done if the local Git clone has not received any updates.)

Comment: Thanks I try to add my repo to the value `repo` however the code is not compiled , I see error in this code `%/.built,$(repos))`

Comment: Sorry about the typo; try again now.

Comment: The issue is with the `$*`

Comment: I've create a 'Makefile` which works for other target (using mac catlina)- GNU Make 3.81
 , not sure how to check what is the issue with your code ,

Comment: There was a problem with the clone operation though; I have updated now to require `%/.git` to be created when you clone, and also to add a phony `clone:` to do just that for all three repos.

Comment: I have tested this on Mojave, GNU Make 3.81

Comment: Partial demo, no access to Github though; but definitely no syntax errors. https://ideone.com/JoqsAr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207675/discussion-between-beno-odr-and-tripleee).

Comment: I think I miss something basic which for you is already clear ...

Comment: You need a space after `patsubst`.

Comment: I closed the question and opened new one , please have a look if you can help as this is probably too complicated and I try to make it more simple ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191402/makefile-run-target-multple-times Thank you@